# Using Windows system trust store to validate server certificates using Indy/OpenSSL

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, indy10

I'm using Delphi 10.4 with Indy 10 updated from GitHub at the end of August.

I'm looking for the best way to let OpenSSL validate a server certificate using the Windows system certificate stores. I’m working with a custom TCP protocol which is not HTTP, so I’m using the `TIdTCPClient` component.

To let OpenSSL validate the server certificate against the local system's trust store, it seems that I have to add them manually into the OpenSSL certificates store. To do this I need to call `X509_STORE_add_cert()` for each cert stored in the Windows cert store.

**First issue** - from a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object, calling `X509_STORE_add_cert()` require to provide a pointer to a `PX509_STORE` variable holding the store, which is indeed wrapped by a `fSSLContext.fContext.cert_store`. As `fContext` is not public, it seems the only way to access to it is to create a class helper where to put my code. Is there a smarter way to proceed ?

**Second issue** - the certs have to be added to the OpenSSL Cert store, but `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLContext` seems to be `nil` until the connection with the server is established. Where is the best place to do this ? It has to be done before making the SSL handshake but after the internal objects wrapping OpenSSL stuff are created and initialized. It seems that overriding `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Init` and putting initialization code here would be the best place, but the method is not virtual ! Is it an error, or by design ? Is there any reason why `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Init` is **static** while `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Init` – the counterpart for server IOHandlers- is **virtual** and could be freely overridden ?

I decided to change Indy code and make `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Init` virtual. This way I can add certs just before connecting to the server :

```
TThSSLContext = class helper for TIdSSLContext
public
  function LoadCertsFromWindowsCertStore(const AStoreName: string): Boolean;
end;

procedure TThIOHandlerSSLBase.Init;
begin
  inherited;
  SSLContext.LoadCertsFromWindowsCertStore('ROOT');
  SSLContext.LoadCertsFromWindowsCertStore('CA');
end;
```

`LoadCertsFromWindowsCertStore()` mimics all the C++ code that can be found in the Internet to import certs from Windows cert store to OpenSSL cert store :

```
function TThSSLContext.LoadCertsFromWindowsCertStore(const AStoreName: string): Boolean;
var
  LWinStore: HCERTSTORE;
  LCert: PCCERT_CONTEXT;
  LX509: PX509;
begin
  Result := True;
  LWinStore := CertOpenSystemStore(0, PChar(AStoreName));
  if LWinStore = nil then
    Exit(False);
  try
    LCert := CertEnumCertificatesInStore(LWinStore, nil);
    while Assigned(LCert) do
    begin
      LX509 := d2i_X509(nil, @lCert.pbCertEncoded, LCert.cbCertEncoded);
      if Assigned(LX509) then
      begin
        if X509_STORE_add_cert(fContext.cert_store, LX509) <= 0 then
          Exit(False);
        X509_free(LX509);
      end;
      LCert := CertEnumCertificatesInStore(LWinStore, LCert);
    end;
  finally
    CertCloseStore(LWinStore, 0);
  end;
end;
```

Doing this seems to work, but is there any better way to verify server certicates through OpenSSL without changing Indy source code and using class helpers to access protected variables ?

Comment: By default, OpenSSL does not touch the Windows cert store, only its own cert store. But IIRC, there is a branch/plugin floating around that updates OpenSSL with support for the Windows cert store. But that is outside the scope of Indy.

Comment: I’m perfectly aware that what I’m trying to achieve is outside the scope of the library. Nevertheless, having to modify Indy source code to perform certificates verifications seems strange for me. Validating certificates against a trust store is a crucial part of SSL, and it was expecting to find more callbacks or accessors to perform this task. Is there at least a better place to initialize OpenSSL cert store than inside TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Init function - which requires to alter Indy source code to make it virtual ?

Comment: The `OnVerifyPeer` event can be used for custom certificate validations. But applying custom settings beforehand is a known issue: [#224: Add event to OpenSSL IOHandler for requsting user-defined SSL/TLS settings](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/224)